Creating keyboard shortcuts for tenkeyless keyboard
I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I'm using a "Tenkeyless" (TKL) keyboard and would like to set up keyboard shortcuts for some ASCII characters I normally use (like the less than < and greater than > sign), for example, CTRL+a+s = <. Is that possible? I haven't found any reliable info on this.

There is no version of Ubuntu called 24. An actual version number would help a lot.

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Please edit the question do not use comments to add info.

It was a simple question. This is why I hate asking in these type of forums, all I get is smugness as answers.

The answer can only be as good as the info in the question.
